# jQuery dialog box not accepting custom css.

Tags: jquery, css

For the life of me I cannot get my dialog box to create a custom CSS class.

```
    function renderShowCriteria()
    {
        var myAccountNo = '@accountNo';
        var model = $('form').serializeArray();
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetCriteriaData", "Search")";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: model,
            success: function (data) {
                var NewDialog = $(data);
                NewDialog.dialog({
                    modal: false,
                    position: ["left", "bottom"],
                    dialogClass: 'shawnTest',
                    buttons:
                     {
                         "Update": function () {$(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); renderShowCriteria(); },
                         "Run": function () { $('#CriteriaForm').submit(); },
                         //"Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); }

                     },
                    close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
```

and my CSS is

```
.ui-dialog .shawnTest {
    height:100%; 
    width: 500px;
}
```

I have tried everything but it will just not accept my CSS.

Comment: Tried `!important` declaration? Making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will improve possible help.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, I am trying to make a fiddle, but our awesome developers have combines ajax, jQuery and c# all in one page and I am trying to sort through it.

Comment: for starters, `var url = "@Url.Action("GetCriteriaData", "Search")";` will give a syntax error. it should be `var url = "@Url.Action('GetCriteriaData', 'Search')";`. you need to be careful when a string contains double/single quotes.

Comment: thank you, ill let them know, I did not write the script code, I am strictly the front end guy, I am going through this huge database trying to style everything and I just keep running into these issues because nobody is giving the dialog boxes their custom classes so I can style that.

Comment: this may be your problem. does the ajax request work? i doubt it since the url is wrong.. press f12 in chrome and click on the network tab to see the request status, the console tab should show syntax errors also.

Comment: Yeah it is the issue, it is failing to load the css because of that, I just informed the guys, I guess we can close this thread now. Thanks guys!

Comment: Wait no, the work is coming in ok. the actual action is coming in ok, but the css is throwing an error.

Comment: changing to that single quote actually breaks it.

Comment: can you show some error messages?

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: I am probably just going to $(this).css it